SSL certificate validation and indirect CRL in C
I am trying to write C code to verify a certificate, including checking the CRL to check if it is revoked.
Certificate chain
Here is the chain of certs, edited for privacy and brevity:
mycert.pem
    Subject: MyCompany
    Issuer: CA1
    Authority Information Access: https://.../ca1.pem
    CRL Distribution Points: https://.../crl.pem

ca1.pem
    Subject: CA1
    Issuer: Root
    Authority Information Access: https://.../root.pem
    CRL Distribution Points: :https://.../ca_crl.pem
    CRL Issuer: Root

root.pem
    Subject: Root
    Issuer: Root

Verifying this chain is easy:
$ cat root.pem ca1.pem > chain.pem
$ openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem mycert.pem
mycert.pem: OK

CRLs
Both mycert.pem and ca1.pem have associated CRLs:
crl.pem
    Issuer: CA2
    Authority Information Access: https://.../ca2.pem

ca_crl.pem
    Issuer: Root

crl.pem is signed by a second inter cert (ca2.pem), with the same root cert:
ca2.pem
    Subject: CA2
    Issuer: Root
    Authority Information Access: https://.../root.pem
    CRL Distribution Points: https://.../ca_crl.pem

Verifying mycert.pem with an indirect CRL
I can verify mycert.pem using openssl this way:
$ openssl verify -CAfile chain.pem -CRLfile ca_crl.pem -CRLfile crl.pem -untrusted ca2.pem -crl_check -extended_crl mycert.pem
mycert.pem: OK

(Using -untrusted for a cert that I should be able to trust is weird, but I found a few posts using this method without questioning it. If this is wrong, feel free to mention it!)
Verifying mycert.pem with an indirect CRL in C
I'm now trying to translate this command to C code, but I can't make it work. Here is a simple piece of code that should reproduce the command's behavior:
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

X509 *cert_load(const char *filename) {
    X509 *cert = NULL;
    FILE *fp   = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp) {
        cert = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return cert;
}

X509_CRL *crl_load(const char *filename) {
    X509_CRL *crl = NULL;
    FILE     *fp  = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp) {
        crl = PEM_read_X509_CRL(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return crl;
}

int main() {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    int ret;
    X509_STORE     *store          = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_CTX *ctx            = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    X509           *mycert         = cert_load("mycert.pem");
    X509           *ca1_cert       = cert_load("ca1.pem");
    X509           *ca2_cert       = cert_load("ca2.pem");
    X509           *root_cert      = cert_load("root.pem");
    X509_CRL       *crl            = crl_load("crl.pem");
    X509_CRL       *ca_crl         = crl_load("ca_crl.pem");
    STACK_OF(X509) *chain          = sk_X509_new_null();
    STACK_OF(X509) *untrusted      = sk_X509_new_null();

    if (!mycert || !ca1_cert || !ca2_cert || !root_cert || !crl || !ca_crl) {
        printf("Error loading certificates or CRL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    sk_X509_push(chain, ca1_cert);

    sk_X509_push(untrusted, ca2_cert);

    X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl);
    X509_STORE_add_crl(store, ca_crl);

    // X509_V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT: enable checking indirect CRL
    X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL | X509_V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT);

    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, root_cert);
    X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, mycert, chain);
    X509_STORE_CTX_set0_untrusted(ctx, untrusted);

    ret = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
    if (ret == 1) {
        printf("Verification successful\n");
    } else {
        int error = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx);
        printf("Verification failed: %s\n", X509_verify_cert_error_string(error));
    }

    X509_STORE_CTX_free(ctx);
    X509_STORE_free(store);
    sk_X509_pop_free(chain, X509_free);
    sk_X509_pop_free(untrusted, X509_free);
    X509_free(mycert);
    X509_free(ca1_cert);
    X509_free(ca2_cert);
    X509_free(root_cert);
    X509_CRL_free(crl);
    X509_CRL_free(ca_crl);

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    return ret;
}


Running the above code, I get KO: unable to get local issuer certificate.
I tried commenting this line: X509_STORE_CTX_set0_untrusted(ctx, untrusted); which gives KO: unable to get certificate CRL.
If I also comment this line: X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL | X509_V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT);, the verification succeeds.
How can I build the "untrusted" chain so that it relies on the root cert, and the CRL is considered as valid for my cert?

What happens if you put ca1_cert and ca2_cert on the same chain? Note that X509_STORE_CTX_set0_untrusted(ctx, untrusted); will replace the untrusted chain chain set by the previous call X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, mycert, chain);.

Both CA certs in the chain:
sk_X509_push(chain, ca1_cert); sk_X509_push(chain, ca2_cert); X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl); X509_STORE_add_crl(store, ca_crl); /* CRL check disabled X509_STORE_set_flags(...); */ X509_STORE_add_cert(store, root_cert); X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, mycert, chain); ret = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
Gets me Verification successful. With CRL checking enabled: Verification failed: unable to get certificate CRL. I wish I knew which certificate though!
Thanks for the heads up about X509_STORE_CTX_set0_untrusted.

#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/x509_vfy.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Function to load a certificate from a file
X509 *cert_load(const char *filename) {
    X509 *cert = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp) {
        cert = PEM_read_X509(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening certificate file %s\n", filename);
    }
    return cert;
}

// Function to load a CRL from a file
X509_CRL *crl_load(const char *filename) {
    X509_CRL *crl = NULL;
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp) {
        crl = PEM_read_X509_CRL(fp, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening CRL file %s\n", filename);
    }
    return crl;
}

int main() {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    int ret;
    X509_STORE *store = X509_STORE_new();
    X509_STORE_CTX *ctx = X509_STORE_CTX_new();
    X509 *mycert = cert_load("mycert.pem");
    X509 *ca1_cert = cert_load("ca1.pem");
    X509 *ca2_cert = cert_load("ca2.pem");
    X509 *root_cert = cert_load("root.pem");
    X509_CRL *crl = crl_load("crl.pem");
    X509_CRL *ca_crl = crl_load("ca_crl.pem");
    STACK_OF(X509) *chain = sk_X509_new_null();
    STACK_OF(X509) *untrusted = sk_X509_new_null();

    if (!mycert || !ca1_cert || !ca2_cert || !root_cert || !crl || !ca_crl) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading certificates or CRL\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Add intermediate certificates to the chain
    sk_X509_push(chain, ca1_cert);
    sk_X509_push(chain, ca2_cert);

    // Add intermediate certificates to the untrusted stack
    sk_X509_push(untrusted, ca1_cert);
    sk_X509_push(untrusted, ca2_cert);

    X509_STORE_add_crl(store, crl);
    X509_STORE_add_crl(store, ca_crl);

    // Set flags for CRL checking
    X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK | X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL | X509_V_FLAG_EXTENDED_CRL_SUPPORT);

    X509_STORE_add_cert(store, root_cert);
    X509_STORE_CTX_init(ctx, store, mycert, chain);
    X509_STORE_CTX_set0_untrusted(ctx, untrusted);

    ret = X509_verify_cert(ctx);
    if (ret == 1) {
        printf("Verification successful\n");
    } else {
        int error = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx);
        printf("Verification failed: %s\n", X509_verify_cert_error_string(error));
    }

    X509_STORE_CTX_free(ctx);
    X509_STORE_free(store);
    sk_X509_pop_free(chain, X509_free);
    sk_X509_pop_free(untrusted, X509_free);
    X509_free(mycert);
    X509_free(ca1_cert);
    X509_free(ca2_cert);
    X509_free(root_cert);
    X509_CRL_free(crl);
    X509_CRL_free(ca_crl);

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    return ret;
}

Try it

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This still gives "Verification failed: unable to get certificate CRL"

There might be some path or permission related issues. Only you would able to know there
